# 74HC238 (Decoder) - Will it use VCC to power channels?

Tags: esp8266, decoder

I am trying to select different combinations of LED's using a 74HC238.

I am testing with an ESP8266, and supplying 3.3v from a regulator LM1117-3.3v.

My question is when I make the digital channels lets say put Y1 to high, will it be using the 3.3v that is being supplied from VCC, or will it go high and use current from the GPI lines?

If so, that means I would need to use a transistor NPN and supply the LED's power from the Regulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

74HC238 will get current internally from its power rail, GPIO (should be in output mode to be proper input for 238) will have minimal current draw.

You need to look at nominal current for LED (in LED datasheet), and ensure that 238's output can provide such current under normal operation (in 238's datasheet), and use limiting resistor in series with LED to limit the current to the nominal value.

Answer (score 2):

The outputs are directly sourced by Vdd and sinked to GND. That's a basic function of logic gates. But be careful, some chips have open-collector/open-drain outputs which means they can only sink the output, not source it. Usually, this comes with more sink current capability and/or with a >>Vdd voltage compatibility at the output. Look at the datasheet. Check the supported currents if you want to drive LEDs. Output current and sum current on Vdd/GND.

It will work with a 74HC238. However, the usual way to do this is using an **inverting decoder** as the 74HC**1**38, and tie the LEDs (plus current-limiting resistor) between the outputs and Vdd. Why? Because most multi-LED arrangements are *common-anode*, which means they have a shared pin for the anode connection.

Comment: It seems I can only source 25 milliamps. I am trying to understand why using an inverting decoder would be better.

Comment: 25mA is enough for one standard LED. As the decoder ensures only one LED is active at a time, you only need one current limiting resistor for all of them. Using an inverting decoder is not *better*, but could be needed when the LED strip you want to use is only available in a common-anode fashion. Because then, the single LEDs in it are controlable by sinking their cathode pins to GND. Which an inverting decoder does. **Or**, when you need another *inverting* amplifier stage after the decoder, and want to have the result non-inverting.

Comment: What if I wanted to connect a sensor that used 45mA?

Comment: Sensor? I think you mean an *actor* e.g. an LED? Then you have to use an additional driver chip which supports these 45mA, eg. the ULN2801. Which is inverting, by the way.

Comment: (oh, and not to forget, the ULN2801 is open-collector, so the correct combo would be HC**2**38 + ULN2801 + common anode led strip.)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The ULN is an NPN transistor?  Reason I say sensor is because I may want to try different scenarios not necessarily just an LED. I don't want sensors powered on all the time. In my current design I am using a multiplexor with a decoder and then  4 npn transistors. The multiplexor is used to collect data from 4 analog sensors. The decoder is used to witch the transistors that power the sensors. Am I making things too complicated? Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: ULN2801 is a 8 x Darlington-NPN array with open collector and commutation diodes. But as you describe it, you propably *cannot* switch the ground line. That is because you have three terminals on the sensors, Vdd, GND and output. When you switched the ground line, power will be flowing between Vdd and the output, making your sensors misbehave. And even if your inputs are high impedance CMOS, your sensors will tie these inputs to Vdd when the GND is lifted. So, don't do that. You need a NPN driver chip with common collector or a PNP driver chip instead. Not common. I would stick to transistors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48074/discussion-between-adl-and-janka).

Answer (score 0):

From the datasheet you can see that you can use the decoder in both modes. In other words the output channel can be used as source or sink. Meaning you can choose yourself what you need. The limitations are the max current that you can sink or supply from a channel. And ofcourse the limitations from the decoder as a unit.

You have to calculate ofcourse the serial resistor for the led.

Answer (score 0):

Current for all outputs on the 74HC238 will be sourced from the +3.3V supply to that IC. The ESP8266 input/output pins will not be asked provide *any* of that current.

Your biggest concern is the maximum current you can expect from those 74HC238 outputs. The [datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2030217.pdf) says that output current is at most 25mA in either direction, per output. That is surprisingly high.

It also tells you that the total supply current for that IC should not exceed 50mA. Since all output current is drawn from the IC's supply, then if outputs are providing 5mA per LED, for instance, you shouldn't have more than 10 LEDs illuminated at a time.

Therefore, if you wish to have more than 50mA total LED current available at any given time, then you'll have to use transistors anyway, or some system that will offload current demand from the 74HC238.